# Unable to mock a method with Mockito and Spring

Tags: spring, mockito, powermock

I have a class JobDelegate for which i am writing unit tests using mockito. I am unable to mock the HTTPOperations class. I have tried using setter injection from test class as well. But it does not work. Below the latest revision of the code. I tried using Power mock. but none of them was helpful. I am unable to predict which is going wrong.

Unit Test code

```
 @ContextConfiguration(locations= "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring- 
context.xml") 
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 //@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 /@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.*" })
  //@PrepareForTest({ HTTPOperations.class})
  public class JobSubmissionDelegateTest{

private static Logger LOGGER = null;

private JobDelegate  jobDelegate ;  

private JobManager  jobImpl;    
@InjectMocks
private HTTPOperations operations;

//@Rule public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
@Before
public void setupTests() {
    jobDelegate = new JobDelegate();
    jobManager = new DBJobManagerImpl();
    operations = new HTTPOperations();
    jobManager.setHttpOperations(operations);
    jobSubmissionDelegate.setJobImpl(jobManager);
    //HTTPOperations httpOperationsSpy =spy(HTTPOperations.class);
    //doReturn("{\"response\":\"{\\\"run_id\\\":32423423}\\n\"}").when(myClassSpy).method1();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

}
@Test
public void testExecuteJob() throws IOException {
//  PowerMockito.mockStatic(HTTPOperations.class);
    Mockito.when(operations.submitHttpPostRequest(any(), anyString())).thenReturn("{\"response\":\"{\\\"run_id\\\":32423423}\\n\"}");
    //System.out.println("==>"+operations.submitHttpPostRequest(null, ""));
    ...........
    int runID = jobDelegate.executeJob(jobDetails);
    System.out.println("Run ID here " + runID);

}
}       


public class JobDelegate {
  // This is an interface.. and the implementation is passed from spring- 
   context.xml
  @Autowired
private JobManager jobImpl;

public int executeJob(JobDTO jobDto) {
............
return jobImpl.runBatchJob(jobDto);

}
}
public class DBJobManagerImpl implements JobManager{

@Autowired
private URIUtils uriUtils;

@Autowired
private HTTPOperations httpOperations;

@Override
public int runBatchJob(JobDTO jobDto) throws Exception {


    UriComponentsBuilder uri = uriUtils.createURI(ConfigUtil.getUrI());

    String response  = httpOperations.submitHttpPostRequest(uri, runSubmitJson);
    System.out.println("Response ==> " +response);
    .................
}
}
```

Comment: InjectMocks is used to create a **real** instance and **inject** mocks into this real instance. It doesn't mock anything. Read the Mockito documentation. And you're not autowiring any bean in your test, so what's the point of annotating with RunWith and ContextConfiguration? And finally, if what you want to test is the JobDelegate class, why do you try to mock HTTPOperations? JobDelegate doesn't depend directly on HTTPOperations. It depends on JobManager. That's what you should mock.

Comment: I need to mock HTTPOperations to cover the test of jobManager implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue using PowerMock. 
Below the code

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(locations= "file:src/main/webapp/WEB- 
 INF/Enrichment_Context.xml") 
 @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.*", 
 "javax.management.*" })
  @PrepareForTest({ HTTPOperations.class})
  public class JobDelegateTest {

@Autowired
private JobDelegate jobSubmissionDelegate;

@Test
public void testExecuteJob() throws IOException {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(HTTPOperations.class);
    PowerMockito.when(HTTPOperations.submitHttpPostRequest(Mockito.any(), 
 Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("{\"response\":\"{\\\"run_id\\\":32423423}\\n\"}");
    ...................
    int runID = jobSubmissionDelegate.executeJobSubmission(jobDetails);
}
}
```